# How to set padding in the divs in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My whole code is this how to set spacing b/w the divs ?It must run smoothly on all devices

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="width:100%">
      <div class="row" style="height:33%">
         <div class="col-xs-3" style="height:100%;background-color:#003380;"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-center"style="height:100%;background-color:#66a3ff;padding-left: 20px">Top </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 " style="height:100%;background-color:#cce0ff"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="height:33%">
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="height:100%;background-color:#66a3ff"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="height:33%">
        <div class="col-xs-3 " style="height:100%;background-color:#cce0ff">left</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 " style="height:100%;background-color:#66a3ff">Center</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 " style="height:100%;background-color:#003380">Right </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap another column around the elements, which makes that the padding of the wrapping column provides some sort of margin/spacing.

Is the below code something you are aiming for?

```css
.spacing {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="width:100%">
      <div class="row" style="height:33%">
         <div class="col-xs-3 spacing">
           <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:100%;background-color:#003380;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6 spacing">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center"style="height:100%;background-color:#66a3ff;padding-left: 20px">Top </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-3 spacing">
           <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:100%;background-color:#cce0ff"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="height:33%">
         <div class="col-xs-3 spacing">
           <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:100%;background-color:#66a3ff"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="height:33%">
         <div class="col-xs-3 spacing">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:100%;background-color:#cce0ff">left</div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6 spacing">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:100%;background-color:#66a3ff">Center</div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-3 spacing">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:100%;background-color:#003380">Right </div>  
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**

Since you are looking for spacing in all directions (and not only left and right), you can just add an extra class to the wrappers called `spacing` and the following CSS: (see updated code snippet)

```
.spacing {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: i think this is not the optimized way & it only adds spacing b/w columns i want spacing in all the four sides equally

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this class to your stylesheet

```
Pad-10{
  padding:1%;
}
```

and then add the class to your divs

```
<div class="row Pad-10" style="height:33%">
```

Comment: Its not working.Btw i have added this inside the div

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve that:

1. By wrapping your each `col` with another `col`

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" style="width:100%">
      <div class="row" style="height:33%">
         <div class="col-xs-3"><div class="col-xs-12" style="height:100%;background-color:#003380;"></div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"><div class="col-xs-12 text-center"style="height:100%;background-color:#66a3ff;padding-left: 20px">Top </div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><div class="col-xs-12 " style="height:100%;background-color:#cce0ff"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="height:33%">
        <div class="col-xs-3"><div class="col-xs-12 " style="height:100%;background-color:#cce0ff">left</div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"><div class="col-xs-12 " style="height:100%;background-color:#66a3ff">Center</div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><div class="col-xs-12 " style="height:100%;background-color:#003380">Right </div></div>  
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This will create default space of `30px` between two column

2. If you wish to create more space then you can use `col-xs-offset` classes from bootstrap. But this will decrease the size of your columns
3. You can always use custom `classes` of your own to change the grid as you want

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be using a flexbox for the row and padding for the flex items.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.row div { padding: 1em; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" style="width:100%">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color:#003380;">X</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-center" style="background-color:#66a3ff;">Top </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 " style="background-color:#cce0ff">X</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color:#66a3ff">X</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 " style="background-color:#cce0ff">left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 " style="background-color:#66a3ff">Center</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 " style="background-color:#003380">Right </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, you want spacing between the divs of class row without a spacing between the container div and its child divs(div.row).

For this you can add bottom margins to all divs except the last div. This can be done as so:

```
div.row{
margin-bottom: [whatever amount of space you want]; //add bottom margin to the row divs
}
div.row:last-child{
margin-bottom: none; //remove bottom margin from the row div that happens to be the last child in its container(i.e. div.container)
}
```

If you want to have spacing between the childs of rows too:

```
div.row{
    margin-bottom: [whatever amount of space you want]; //add bottom margin to the row divs
    }
div.row:last-child{
    margin-bottom: none; //remove bottom margin from the row div that happens to be the last child in its container(i.e. div.container)
}
div.col-xs-3{
    margin: [top margin], 0, [bottom margin], 0;
}
div.col-xs-6{
    margin: [topmargin], 0, [bottom margin], 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aviral Garg Please check following code. I have modified style properties in your code and added classes "common_row" & "common_box" in it, with some properties. You can adjust padding in "common_box" class & margin-bootom in "common_row" class according to your need. It will work fine on all devices as I have added grid classes in it. I hope you were expecting the same.

```css
.common_row{
height:33%;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

.common_row .common_box{
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container" style="width:100%">
      <div class="row common_row">
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 common_box" style="background-color:#003380;"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center common_box"style="background-color:#66a3ff;">Top </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 " style="background-color:#cce0ff"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row common_row" style="height:33%">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 common_box" style="background-color:#66a3ff"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row common_row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 common_box" style="background-color:#cce0ff">left</div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 common_box" style="background-color:#66a3ff">Center</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 common_box" style="background-color:#003380">Right </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
```